# Moving items from QTreeWidget to QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, qtreewidget

Im trying to move the items that is checked to the empty list when the user press the ''Ok'' button.
But i get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Desktop/abstract.py", line 42, in okButtonSlot
    self.listWidget.addItem(item) TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   addItem(self, QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTreeWidgetItem'   addItem(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTreeWidgetItem'
```

This is how the program looks:
[image]

And this is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QListWidget, QPushButton, 
QTreeWidgetItem, QWidget, QTreeWidget

parameterList = ["Suction", "Discharge", "Oil", "Motor", "Capacity"]

class TreeTilList(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabel("Parameter")
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.okButton = QPushButton("Ok")

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.okButtonSlot)

        self.parameter = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget, ["Control values"])
        self.items = list()

        for i in parameterList:
            item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.parameter, [i])
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
            item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.items.append(item)

        layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.okButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def okButtonSlot(self):
        for item in self.items:
            if item.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                self.listWidget.addItem(item)

            else:
                print(item.checkState(0))


def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TreeTilList()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

window()
```

Comment: When i do: self.listWidget.addItem(str(item), it will add the items to the list, but the items object address instead of their value

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that QTreeWidgetItem is not the same as QListWidgetItem, so you must get the information from the first and copy it to the second:

```py
def okButtonSlot(self):
    for item in self.items:
        if item.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            list_item = QListWidgetItem(item.text(0))
            self.listWidget.addItem(list_item)
```